# How to create new object from old one with filtered values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
const items = {
  a: [3,5],
  b: [6,7,8],
  c: [0,10,1111]
}
```

and the array:

```
const existing = [3,8]
```

I'd like to create a new object, but without values that are included in the existing array. I mean this one:

```
const newItems = {
  a: [5],
  b: [6,7],
  c: [0,10,1111]
}
```

Please about the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    const items = {
      a: [3,5],
      b: [6,7,8],
      c: [0,10,1111]
    }
    
    const existing = [3,8]
    
    
    const result = Object.keys(items).reduce((acc, key ) => {
      acc[key] = items[key].filter((item)=> !existing.includes(item))
      return acc;
    }, {})
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` along with `filter` to get the required result.

```js
const items = {
  a: [3, 5],
  b: [6, 7, 8],
  c: [0, 10, 1111],
}

const existing = [3, 8]

const newEntries = Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  value.filter((x) => !existing.includes(x))
])


const newObject = Object.fromEntries(newEntries)
```